# Slip in and out vs. slide in and out

Tags: word-choice

**To *slide* in and out or to *slip* in and out**: which of the following is correct and why?

1. This way, you can easily slide the bag organizer in and out [of your
   handbag]
2. This way, you can easily slip the bag organizer in and out [of your
   handbag]

*Used in another sentence*

1. We've found hardware can damage the inside of your bag when the organizer is slipped in and out
2. We've found hardware can damage the inside of your bag when the organizer is slid in and out

Comment: They're both correct.  The organizer is presumably something rigid, like a box, not a bag within a bag?

Comment: Note that *slip and slide* is also a verbal phrase. So, just to make things more complicated, things can actually *slip and slide in and out* in some contexts. (Although, normally, that phrasing wouldn't be used in either of your example sentences. I would probably use it to describe trying to hold a bar of soap in the shower, for instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Slip"* is more commonly a description of an intentional action of discreetly moving oneself or an object:

"Slip that money into your pocket - don't let your mother see."

*"Slide"* more usually describes the smoothness of the action itself:

"The new, slim-design phone, will slide right into your pocket."

So, if you are marketing discreetness, for example: nondescript packaging of a personal item - you might emphasize how it  *slips* away, unnoticed.

If you are selling the "convenience" of size or shape, *slide* may be preferred. AmE

Answer (score 0):

**Slide** is the more neutral choice. At one level, *slip* and *slide* are identical in meaning. However, each word has its own set of connotations drawn from their various uses over the years, e.g. “Slip him a [mickey](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn_(drugs)).”

Sometimes, technical writing benefits from a playful style. For example, I once had a cell phone manual with the memorable line: “All those in favor of improved reception, raise your antennas.” After pages of button icons and screenshots, this came as a welcome break.

So there’s no “right choice” between *slip* and *slide* in the examples you gave. However, if you’re writing about the insides of women’s handbags, *slip* might give your text a lighter and more feminine tone.